# Extract two different vectors from set in R

Tags: r

How can I extract the set of (a) and set of (b) as shown in the image to two different vectors, the first vector for (a) values and the second for (b) values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using names

```
> tmp=c("a"=1,"b"=2,"a"=3,"b"=5)
> tmp[names(tmp)=="a"]
a a 
1 3
```